# JavaFX DatePicker - remove textbox

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

I would like to use the JavaFX datepicker but I do not want the text box - I just want to show the button.

Is there a way to:

1. Remove the textbox?
2. Increase the width of the button on the datepicker elements (I can cover the textbox if this is the only way)

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this answer, it worked for me perfectly.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836036/javafx-show-only-the-button-of-a-date-picker-and-not-the-editor/50841127#50841127

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I released some JavaFX controls based on the Java 8 Date & Time API, including a [LocalDateChooser](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.10/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/fx/scene/control/time/LocalDateChooser.html) which you could use for your scenario.

There is an [old blog post](https://puces-blog.blogspot.com/2013/04/drombler-commons-javafx-controls-for.html), but please note that some packages etc. changed in the meantime.

The controls are available from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-time</artifactId>
  <version>0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

The library is [Open Source](https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons).