# javafx show only the button of a date picker and not the editor

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I have a javafx datePicker and I want to be shown without text editor at all. I want only the button of the picker to be visible and active. Is there any way to do this. Of course I tried the datePicker.getEditor().setVisible(false) but there is stil an annoying place holder which I want to make invisible.

DatePickerView.fxml

```
<HBox>
   <children>
       <TextField/>
       <DatePicker fx:id="datePicker">
           <opaqueInsets>
              <Insets/>
           </opaqueInsets>
        </DatePicker>  
   </children>
</Hbox>
```

DatePickerController.java

```
public class DatePickerComtroller implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    DatePicker datePicker;
    @FXML
    HBox container;

    public DatePickerComtroller(){
    }

    public initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
       datePicker.getEditor().setVisible(false);
    }
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt `new DatePicker()`???

Comment: Not sure if he can do it. Datepicker is an input, not a "tool" like you want it to be... Maybe you can make it "always visible", but I don't think you can make it "independant" from the input... Maybe someone can confirm this?

Comment: what do you want to appear instead of the textField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't describe what you want to show instead of the textField, I assume that you want the button to fill the total width. Whatever, the collaborator that's responsible for creating, configuring and layouting the children of a control is its skin. So basically, you'll need a custom skin and tweak what you want to change, here: the layout.

What to do:

- subclass DatePickerSkin
- in its constructor, get hold of the arrowButton (it's private, but you can look it up via its style)
- override layoutChildren, remove the editor and change the width of the button to fill the width

Some raw code example (obviously there's leeway for polishing :)

```
public class MyPickerSkin extends DatePickerSkin {

    StackPane arrowButtonAlias;
    public MyPickerSkin(DatePicker control) {
        super(control);
        arrowButtonAlias = (StackPane) control.lookup(".arrow-button");
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, h);
        // seems the removal must happen after super's layout (see OPs comment)
        getChildren().remove(getEditor());
        arrowButtonAlias.resizeRelocate(x, y, w, h);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works perfect for me and yes your assumption was correct that I want the button to fill all width. The only small correction in your solution is to place the **super.layoutChildren(x,y,w,h)** call before the **getChildren().remove(getEditor())** otherwise there are some problems with the painting of the button.(It seems that it needs focus to finish the painting).

Comment: glad it helped :) Thanks for the info, edited and changed sequence of calls